# How to change the HTML Output of a view?

Tags: views

This view is a black book directory that will have a long list of links to static pages. The problem I am having is the output isn't coming out as an unordered list like I have set. Each link is set in a span and a row. Is it possible to output a simple ul with an id on it. I am having trouble matching my design.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the view style to "HTML List," then the style option to "Unordered list."

Answer (score 7):

Drupal likes to put `<span>` and `<div>` around every item. When you don't like that, you can override the PHP file that's causing this.

Look in the `sites/all/modules/views/theme` folder at the `views-view-list.tpl.php`, `views-view-field.tpl.php` and `views-view-fields.tpl.php` files.

Save a copy of these files in your own theme's 'templates' folder. Then you can edit the copies to strip code that makes  `<span>` and `<div>` etc. You should also rename your version of these files according to the view's template suggestions so the changes only affect your view.

I used this for a view where I wanted to make 3 columns, so I wanted the classes li_1, li_2 and li_3 (in file `views-view-list.tpl.php`)

```
<?php
// $Id: views-view-list.tpl.php,v 1.3 2008/09/30 19:47:11 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
 * @file views-view-list.tpl.php
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * - $title : The title of this group of rows.  May be empty.
 * - $options['type'] will either be ul or ol.
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */

global $cnt_ul;
global $cnt_li;
$cnt_ul++;

$classNameUl = (($cnt_ul % 3) == 0)? "ul_". $cnt_ul ." last" : "ul_". $cnt_ul;
?>
<ul class="<?php print $classNameUl ?>">
<?php
foreach ($rows as $id => $row): $cnt_li++;
$className = (($cnt_li % 3) == 0)? "li_". $cnt_li ." last" : "li_". $cnt_li;
?>
<li class="<?php print $className ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could I modify this to add an li for each letter of the alphabet with a special id and class to the list? I am trying to make an iphone-like contact list/directory of links all in alphabetical order

Comment: I do have each of these files tailored specifically to the view I am working with. I am failing to understand your code as I hardly know any PHP. I am sure it is possible to programmaticly write some code to add a line like this: <li id="A" class="highlight">A</li> for each letter of the alphabet. Can you help me figure out what I should do make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

You should also take a look at the [Semantic Views module](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews), which allows you to change the HTML output of the view from within the Views UI and largely avoid getting involved in template files.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can style the lists.You probably have just one field in views that is Tittle so just add this to style.css in theme css folder

```
.view-view-name .views-field-title 
{

}
```

Where view-name is a machine name of your View(you can find that in views settings )

Comment: But i'm still getting the links wrapped in span tags. I need <ul id="..."><li>...